# How to add just one page in Arabic

Tags: multi-language

Hi I have a WordPress site where all the content is in English, however I need just one page to be in Arabic with left to right text, plus some bullets which obviously appear on the right instead of on the left, how do I go about creating such a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@toscho is right about the direction of the text...

But as someone who builds websites in hebrew all the time i would reccomend
you create a custom page template by putting this tag in a copy of page.php

```
/*
Template name: arabic page
*/
```

THen you can design it differently... maybe remove the sidebar which is probably in english
maybe make the structure different... you can even make the design a little bit different by loading additional css..

in that page you should use @toscho advice but i would implant the dir="rtl" command directly into that page so you would have better control.

Comment: Yes, this is better … unless you want to write a post, not a page. To get templates for posts use the [Custom Post Template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/).

Comment: right as useall @toscho :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a container to your markup:

```
<div dir="rtl"> your page content here </div>
```

If the post editor strips out the attribute, either post as (user role:) editor, or extend the list of allowed elements and attributes per plugin.